# Can you recommend imu sensor?

Tags: imu

I am making a self-driving car.
I use ros2 humble.
I need imu sensor and driver.
Can you recommend imu sensor and driver?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what use is a `yes` answer?